# Error while resizing image: "error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'resize'"

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to preprocess images dataset, represented in numpy array with images of shape `(28, 28)` by rescaling them to `(10, 10)`. I wrote a function for that:

```py
import cv2 as cv

def resize_dataset(images):
    resized_images = []
    for img in images:
            img = img.reshape((28,28))
            resized_img = cv.resize(img, dsize=(10, 10))
            resized_images.append(resized_img)
    return numpy.array(resized_images)
```

But when I actually try to rescale them, I get the following error in `cv.resize`:

```
error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3662: error: (-215:Assertion failed) func != 0 in function 'resize'
```

In google I only found people with the same error writing on c++ doing very different stuff, like this one: [resize an image and changing its depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385465/resize-an-image-and-changing-its-depth) and this: http://answers.opencv.org/question/19715/error-215-func-0-in-function-convertto/

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Oh, I actually figured it out. Images in the dataset were of type `np.int64`. I just had to convert images to `float32`, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def resize_dataset(images):
    resized_images = []
    for img in images:
            img = img.reshape((28,28)).astype('float32')  # <-- convert image to float32
            resized_img = cv.resize(img, dsize=(10, 10))
            resized_images.append(resized_img)
    return numpy.array(resized_images)
```

And now it works nicely. It looks like `cv.resize` can't work with images represented in int. Hope this will help anyone

Comment: Does anyone knows why it does not work with `int64`? I also found out that it does not work with `int32` but it does work with `uint8`

Comment: Would be nice if the error message explained this :\

Comment: I'm grateful for your sharing of solution! I'm stuck with this problem too. This is the first time I found opencv function receive only float data, but why? And I don't see this written in the document.

Comment: The reason why uint8 is accepted is because the range 0 to 255 can be represented with 8 bits, its that its working with float32.

Answer (score 7):

Actually `cv2.resize` **can** work with images represented in integer, but you need to change the default *interpolation* method.

Here are listed the different Interpolation flags you can use : [OpenCV resize interpolation flags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

By default, cv2 uses the INTER_LINEAR method that, as its name suggests, is linear. So, most of the time it leads to give you values that must be represented as floats. Same with INTER_CUBIC, INTER_AREA, INTER_LANCZOS4...

But there are methods that can be applied on integers, like INTER_NEAREST (nearest neighbor) or INTER_LINEAR_EXACT (same as INTER_LINEAR, but rounded to the nearest integer).

In the aforementioned case, i would have suggested to try :

```py
import cv2
resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (10,10), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT)
```

Comment: `INTER_LINEAR_EXACT` still gives me the same error with `int32` images (OpenCV(4.5.4-dev), C++). `INTER_NEAREST` works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for this. The solution is to have your input image in `uint8` format or `float32`.

Using numpy, it becomes...

```py
my_image = np.array(my_image, dtype='uint8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's check the range of the image whether between [0 1] or not. I got an error cause my RGB in range 255.